# Leetcode #15: 3sum -- avoiding duplicate

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

FYI problem statement:

> Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in S such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
>
> **Note**: The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.
>
> For example, given array S = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
>
> A solution set is: [   [-1, 0, 1],   [-1, -1, 2] ]

Below is my algorithm that works reasonably and as expected, but I'm unable to figure out how to prevent duplicates. I've commented the parts which I tried to keep a track of the duplicate sets(triplets).

```
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums)
{
    vector< vector<int> > res;
    int a,b,c,start,end;
    int preva=0,prevb=0,prevc=0;  //variables to track elements of
                                  //triplet pushed into result 
                                  //vector the previous run.

    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
    int n=nums.size();
    for(int i=0; i<=n-3;i++){
        a = nums[i];
        start = i+1;
        end = n-1;
        while (start < end){
            b = nums[start];
            c = nums[end];
            if (a+b+c == 0)
            {
                if ((a!=preva)&&(b!=prevb)&&(c!=prevc)) //check if duplicate
                    res.push_back({a,b,c}); //add triplet 
                                            //to res vector if not
                                            //present.
                end = end - 1;
                preva=a;
                prevb=b;
                prevc=c;
               }

            else if (a+b+c > 0)
                end = end - 1;
            else
                start = start + 1;

        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

I get,

> Your answer: [[-1,-1,2]]

which doesn't match

> Expected answer: [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]

I'm missing adding the [-1,0,1] altogether when instead it should get added to the vector only once.

Comment: You can use `std;:set` instead of `std::vector` to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the conditional expression in the following `if` statement:

> ```
>             if ((a!=preva)&&(b!=prevb)&&(c!=prevc)) //check if duplicate
> ```

This will *only* push the result if none of `a,b,c` match `preva,prevb,prevc`; in the `[-1,0,1]` case, we end up having `a = -1` match `preva = -1` from `[-1,-1,2]`. Besides, this only checks against the immediately previous solution.

Instead, you should determine an order-independent means of storing these results and let the container itself handle duplicates--perhaps [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) rather than `vector`?